# What's going wrong in this Knock script?

Tags: debian, scripting

It seems by the article [How to read an ACSM file on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1027608/how-to-read-an-acsm-file-on-linux/1775619#1775619) that [knock](https://github.com/esn/knock) is not supported anymore, but some variants seem to be working.
I did before running the script

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads/knock-main$ sudo mv knock /usr/local/bin/
```

My $PATH:

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads/knock-main$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I run the [knock](https://github.com/esn/knock) script:

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads/knock-main$ knock /home/masi/Downloads/URLLink.acsm
```

Output

```
This device is not registered with Adobe.
Enter your Adobe account's email address: MASI@gmail.com
Enter your Adobe account's password: 
Registering this device with Adobe...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/knock", line 32, in <module>
    result = subprocess.run([
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'adept-register'
```

OS: Debian latest
Hardware: ASUS TUF DASH T15

Comment: The python-script `knock` tries to call another script, called `adept-register`, which obvoiusly could not be found. Maybe it is not installed or not in a pleace, where other programs reside (`$PATH`).

Comment: @rathier I added my $PATH.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 where is the `adept-register` program installed?

Comment: @ChrisDavies I cannot find it. I cannot find it in apt-cache or online. Maybe depreciated?